# Update entity data model from database

Tags: asp.net

when i update the database with some new relationship between tables, is there a way to update the edmx file as well?

(when i click update model from database, seems nothing changes)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Open .edmx file in Visual Studio and then simply right click on "Update model from database" and then select any table you need from the Add tab.

If nothing else works you can simply select all the tables delete them and then do the procedure mentioned above.

Answer (score 2):

Right click on the designer and select "Update model from database". Then use the "Refresh" tab to pull any additional information down.